# Macro variables: Why is there whitespace between 2 macro variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

**Why does this return spaces/tab between 2 variables(JAN   2006)?**

I have pasted my code below.

I am trying to automate the date in the filename. The problem here is is that it's used multiple times in the query and it's usually run backwards in time on a monthly basis.

So I have setup a simple macro variable that filters on the dates, but the filename isn't as easily updated. Any tips or suggestions?

If it wasn't on a monthly basis I would have simply used %sysdate function.

[Example filename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQSxe.png)

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE TEST AS    
        SELECT * FROM SASHELP.RENT
        ;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
        SELECT TRIM(YEAR(MAX(date)))
        INTO :year
        FROM test;
RUn;

PROC SQL;
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=1
                THEN "JAN"
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=2
                THEN "FEB"              
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=3
                THEN "MAR"          
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=4
                THEN "APR"              
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=5
                THEN "MEI"              
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=6
                THEN "JUN"              
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=7
                THEN "JUL"              
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=8
                THEN "AUG"              
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=9
                THEN "SEP"              
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=10
                THEN "OKT"              
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=11
                THEN "NOV"
                WHEN MONTH(MAX(DATE))=12
                THEN "DEC"
                END AS maand
        INTO :maand
        FROM test;
RUn;


PROC EXPORT 
DATA=test
outfile = "\\test-&maand&year"
dbms =xlsx replace;
RUN;
```

Comment: Why are you using a character function, TRIM(), on a numeric value, result of the YEAR() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would simplify it.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select year(date)
       , put(month(date), monname3.) 
  into :year separated by ''
     , :month separated by ''
  from sashelp.rent
  having max(date) = date;
run;

%put &year.;
%put &month.;

%put \\test-&month.&year.;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the character function TRIM() on a numeric value.

```
11   select trim(year(max(date))) into :year from sashelp.rent;
ERROR: Function TRIM requires a character expression as argument 1.
```

If you don't want spaces in the value of the macro variable YEAR then do not add the spaces to begin with.

For example you could use one of these methods:

```
select year(max(date)) into :year trimmed from sashelp.rent;
select max(date) format=year4. into :year from sashelp.rent;
select year(max(date)) format=4. into :year from sashelp.rent;
```

Or you could just remove the spaces after creating the macro variable with the spaces.

```
select year(max(date)) into :year from sashelp.rent;
%let year=&year;
```